# How to get the first match of a regex in a string?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

How can I read the first substring that matches my pattern?
I have tried with

```
while (m.find()) {
              URL=(m.group(1));

            }
```

With 1 in the `group` call the app crashes, and if I put nothing in it I get only the last match, I have to read the first matched string, how can I do?
It give me an error about regex, but it's strange because without the 1 in between the () the app works good and don't give me any error about my regex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does it crash? What is the regex? `group(0)` is the whole match and `group(i), i >0` will give you the captures in the regex if any. Also `while(m.find())` processes the string until any matches left. So call `find()` only once if you need the first match.